# Angularjs filter for more then on text values

Tags: angularjs

I want to filter data with multiple values. I am using data like below

```
$scope.data = [
    {'name': 'Apple', 'flavour': 'ammonia'}
    {'name': 'Banana', 'flavour': 'grape, butter'}
    {'name': 'Banana', 'flavour': 'mango, lemon, lemon'} ]
```

JS is

```
 $scope.selecedflavor = [];
     $scope.includeFlavour = function(flavour) {
    var i = $.inArray(flavour, $scope.selecedflavour);
    if (i > -1) {
        $scope.selecedflavour.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
        $scope.selecedflavour.push(flavour);
    }
}
  $scope.flavourFilter = function(data) {
    if ($scope.selecedflavour.length > 0) {
        if ($.inArray(data.flavour, $scope.selecedflavour) < 0)
            return;
    }

    return data;
}
```

Html is as

```
   <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeFlavour('ammonia')"/> Ammonia</li>
           <li> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeFlavour('butter')"/> Butter</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeFlavour('grape')"/> Grape</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeFlavour('mango')"/> Mango</li>
           <li> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeFlavour('lemon')"/> Lemon</li>
           <li> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeFlavour('tea')"/> Tea</li>
      </ul>
```

and my data filter is something like below

```
 <div ng-repeat="f in data | filter:flavour">
```

Is there any option to add multiple value like I have added two flavour for the banana.

Comment: if you wanna use multiple flavours then flavour field should be an array not a string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data would look something like this:

```
$scope.data = [
    {'name': 'Apple', 'flavour': ['one'] },
    {'name': 'Banana', 'flavour': ['one', 'two']}
]
```

You could implement the filter e.g. like this:

```
  app.filter('flavour', function() {
    return function flavourFilter(item, filterValue) {
      return item.flavour.indexOf(filterValue) > -1;
    };
  });
```

And then use it like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="f in data | filter:'two'">
```